# doPostback Error

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to execute a javascript function on page load and then do a postback that would call a function in code behind. I am getting time zone data and trying to pass them as arguments to __dopostback. Here is what I have (abbreviated):

in .aspx file

```
<body onload="GetLocalTime()">
....
function GetLocalTime(){debugger
    var d = new Date();
    var tzOffset = d.getTimezoneOffset();
    var hfOffset = document.getElementById('<%=hfOffset.ClientID%>');
    var hfTZName = document.getElementById('<%=hfTZName.ClientID%>');
    var tzName = getTimezoneName();
    hfOffset.value = tzOffset;
    hfTZName.value = tzName;
    __doPostBack('TZSessionVars', tzOffset, tzName);
}
```

In code behind's Page_Load(), if IsPostback is true:

```
string sTarget = Request["__EVENTTARGET"];
if (sTarget.Equals("TZSessionVars"))
{
    string sArg = Request["__EVENTARGUMENT"];
    SetTZSessionVars(sArg);  // this is where I parse the argument and set session vars
}
```

When I trace the javascript, when it hits __doPostback, it says:Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object expected

The parameters tzOffset and tzName are OK and have valid values.

Comment: I am not passing the hidden fields, but the values of offset and time zone name. When I trace it, they contain "300" and "US/Eastern"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the __EVENTARGUMENT as explained in this article.

[Doing or Raising Postback using __doPostBack() function from Javascript in Asp.Net](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/320_Doing_or_Raising_Postback_using___doPostBack%28%29_function_from_Javascript_in_AspNet.aspx)

Try passing concatenated values as a single __EVENTARGUMENT and split it at server to get actual arguments

Comment: I tried it and still getting the same error. I added a hidden ASP button with an OnClick event and changed __doPostback to __doPostBack('Button1', 'TZSessionVars') to force a button click of Button1.

Comment: I need to read the document more carefully! After adding ClientScript.GetPostBackEventReference(this, "") to page_load, it worked fine. Thanks.